# How can I let player two finish?

Tags: gran-turismo-sport

We are newbies to GranTurismo Sport and when one player wins it just stops the race and the second player doesn't get to finish. Is there a way to change this so player can finish the race?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no. Once the race is won it’s over.

Online races don’t work the same way though.